# Is Mint allowed to share user data with other Intuit entities?

Tags: mint.com

Mint seems like that great piece of software to help show, or at least gather the pieces of, the big picture in one place that we've all thought about crafting but didn't. I'm fine Mint having this information I want just as much, and using it to offer services as they do with TurboTax, but I can't tell from [its privacy policy](https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/security/policy/#a-1) which parts of Intuit has sharing privileges.

Since it's a successful and growing company, there's no telling what businesses they'll expand into, so I'm apprehensive about giving this sort of behavioral insight to an umbrella company.

Is Mint user data isolated within Mint, or is it an Intuit property in the holistic sense of its business, wherever that business may take them?

Comment: Given that the privacy policy begins by saying "Intuit is committed...", I would guess they are not drawing a strong distinction between Mint data and Intuit data.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks, maybe I should just ask Mint. Is this off-topic, btw?

Comment: Personally I would consider it on topic, but it doesn't look like anyone knows the answer.

Comment: To some extent I'd assume the share the data with non-Intuit entities. If you aren't paying for it, you are likely the product and not the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up asking Mint over email so I'll share the answer I received:

> Thank you for contacting Mint.com.
>
> From my understand you want to know if Mint can transfer data to other
>   Intuit products and vice versa. Let me address your concern based from
>   what I can see on my tools.
>
> Upon confirming, while Mint and other Intuit products are under the
>   same company, Mint.com is not yet integrated to other Intuit products.
>   We’d like to thank you though for giving the idea to us. With this, we
>   would know which future enhancements will our customers appreciate.
>
> We have forwarded your request/suggestion to our Product and
>   Development team for their review. At this time though, we can't make
>   any guarantee that your request/suggestion will get implemented as we
>   must balance customer demand with resources and business objectives.

Oops...

Comment: I'm sure they were already headed in that direction; no harm, no foul.

Comment: They probably thought you were asking if you could export your data from Mint to TurboTax, to make tax time easier. I could see that being useful to a lot of people.

Comment: In following this through, I don't think there's any coherence in the life of an end-user contact. I imagine some pressurized queue type of thing, going to a role-type inbox.